# The gambler with initial capital and De Moivre–Laplace theorem.

Tags: probability, statistics

> The gambler with initial capital 1 participated in a game which toss
>   an independent symmetrical coin. In the case when a single Head
>   falls, the player loses half his capital, otherwise his capital
>   doubles. Calculate the approximate likelihood that this 10 000
>   coin-tossed gambler will exceed 1024.

Basic idea: 
$$ X_{i}(\omega) = \begin{cases}
 1  & \text{for $\omega=Tail$}
 \\[2ex] -1 & \text{for $\omega = Head$} \end{cases} $$

$S_{n} = X_{1} + X_{2} + \ldots X_{10000} $

and compute:

$\mathbb{P}(2^{S_{n}}>1024) = \mathbb{P}({S_{n}}>10)$

I would use De Moivre–Laplace theorem, but I don't know how compute $\Phi(z)$ - the normal distribution function.

Edit:

$\Bbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^{10000} \left[X_i]\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{10000} \Bbb{E}\left[X_i\right] = 0 $, because we have $\Bbb{E} \left[X_i\right]=0$.

$X_i$ are independent and $\mathrm{Var(X_{i})=1}$:

$\mathrm{Var[\sum_{i=1}^{10000}} \left[X_i]\right]=\sum_{i=1}^{10000} \mathrm{Var\left[X_i\right]} = 10000$

$\mathbb{P}({\frac{S_{n}-0}{\sqrt{10000}}}>\frac{10-0}{100}) \thickapprox \Phi(0.1)$

Comment: You might want to double check the calculation of the mean and standard deviation of $S_n$. Note that each $X_i$ has mean $0$ and standard deviation $1$.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth I agree, I can not write $\frac{1}{2}10000$ Do you have idea how correct them?

Comment: $\newcommand{\E}{\Bbb{E}}\newcommand{\S}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10000}X_i}\newcommand{\Sum}{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10000}}\newcommand{\Var}{\operatorname{Var}}$Use the fact that $\E\left[\S\right]=\Sum \E\left[X_i\right]$ and $\Var\left(\S\right) =\Sum \Var\left(X_i\right)$.